# Is it possible to view by type in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive

I know I used to be able to view my docs by type (document, spreadsheet, presentation, et) but cannot figure out how to do that with the new look. Did google get rid of it?

Answer (score 4):

You can still do that.

Click the little arrow on the very right hand side of the search box. You get a drop down that you can filter by type:

[image: Google Docs - Filter by Type]